# How do I convert a double into a dateTime value in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to convert a double in to a datetime.

This is not a conversion from Excel. I have a double representing seconds and would simply like it represented as time in minutes and seconds.

121.0005 = 2:01 mins

Comment: That isn't what a `DateTime` means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan`:

```
double seconds = 121.0005;
TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
Console.Write(string.Format("{0} mins", sp.ToString(@"m\:ss")));
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `DateTime` what you need is `TimeSpan`, since your input is representing a time value, not `Date`.

Use [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
double sec = 121.0005;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec);
```